# How do I uninstall a Windows service using a PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to find and uninstall a Windows service.

How can I accomplish this using a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "name='<service_name>'").Delete()
```

For more information:
[Get-WmiObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315295.aspx)
[Delete method of the Win32_Service class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389960%28VS.85%29.aspx)